# How to uncheck a checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to uncheck a dynamically created checkbox. When the checkbox is clicked I need to see whether the value is already present in the database or. If present, then I want to uncheck the checkbox. I tried different ways, but nothing is working.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.subareachk', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '{!! url('validatesubarea') !!}',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
      'id': id,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        alert('Already a Store has been assigned for this sub area');
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: `prop('checked', false)` is correct. The issue is that `this` in the `success` handler function does not reference the `.subareachk` element which raised the event. Check the duplicate for more information and the solution.

Comment: since `$(this).prop('checked', false); ` is inside the success callback, `$(this)` does not refers to checkbox.  before the ajax call assign this to another variable, like `var that = $(this)`, then change your `$(this).prop('checked', false); ` to `that.prop('checked', false); `

Comment: @AkhilAravind thanks for replying .I will try now

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you it is working now

Comment: @AkhilAravind thank you it is working now

Comment: works fr me too :)